# Kernel panic at shut down

Tags: macos, shutdown, kernel-panic

I recently upgraded my MacBook Pro from 10.6.8 to 10.7 (and now 7.1 & 7.2).

Ever since the switch to Lion my Mac has a kernel panic at shutdown and I get the "You need to restart your computer" error message.

I've reset the PRAM and SMC but that made no difference. Booting in safe mode didn't help either. I also unplugged everything from the Mac (monitor, keyboard, mouse, etc.) but it still kernel panics.

Here are a couple logs with [peripherals attached](http://pastebin.com/AK5S20W2) and [without](http://pastebin.com/60n8wPfY).

How can I prevent this shut down kernel panic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both panic logs indicate the panic happened in the org.openafs.filesystems.afs extension, so that's the logical suspect.  The [OpenAFS page for Mac OS X](http://www.openafs.org/macos.html) seems to indicate that version 1.6.0 is current, and lists separate installs for different versions of OS X. Your panic logs indicate you have 1.6.0fc7, which is presumably a final candidate, not the actual release.  I'd disable the extension first, then try installing the current Lion version.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Logs you have VMWare Fusion 3.1.3 installed - there are some people having Troubles with that Version (and Lion), even though it occurs while updating (see [here](http://communities.vmware.com/message/1800072)) to that version. I would recommend the following steps

1. I would try deinstalling VMWare 3.1.3 or Upgrading to the current Version 4.1.
2. According to the Apple Support Pages for resolving [Kernel Panic Errors for 10.7](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mchlp2890.html) you have taken the necessary first steps, but did you try the Hardware Test as well (mentioned [here](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.7/en/mh35727.html))?

There are further Informations to resolve Kernel Panic Issues at '[The XLabs](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/kernelpanics.html)' (helpful, even though only up to 10.6).

Please tell about the results.